# Database Connection Close Issue - Robot Framework

Tags: database, jdbc, robotframework

I am trying to close database connection in Robot Framework using `Disconnect from database keyword` and unable to do so and getting an error msg

> Attribute error: None type object has no attribute close.

Can anyone help me how can I close this connection in Robot Framework?

using below keywords in order:

```
connect to database using params   jaydebeapi  '${db2driver}', '${db2url}',['{db2username}', '${db2pswd}'], '${db2driverpath}'          
${query}=  catenate select count(*) from table    
${result}=  databaselibrary.Query  ${query}    
disconnect from database   
connect to database using params jaydebeapi  '${jdbcdriver}', '${oracledburl}',['{oracleusername}', '${oraclepswd}'], '${jdbcdriverpath}'
```

Comment: Share some code how you're connecting and working with the database - that error can be anything, most probable you don't have an active connection.

Comment: This works fine while running scripts individually but facing the issue while trying to switch DB connections from Oracle DB to DB2 or vice versa. Using the following function to disconnect, self._disconnection.close()

Comment: I'm sure the error is troublesome for you - but without the code you're using, it's impossible to get any help from the community; see my previous comment. Also, you're citing a python code `self._disconnection` - is your question about RF in the first place, or pure python?

Comment: This is python method being used in robot framework as a keyword which i am using for disconnection.Code is as given below                                         def connect_to_database_using_custom_params(self,dbapiModuleName                                     =None,db_connect_string=' ') method of DatabaseLibrary for connection    and def disconnect_from_db(self):       self._dbconnection.close()  for closing. Steps I m following are:1.connecting db2 2.executing query 3.closing connection 4.connecting oracle db

Comment: Those are the library's method signatures alright, but how do you actually invoke them in your tests, or keywords? Add that code - to the question's body. And add what is the outcome of step 2 - if step 1 succeeds in the first place.

Comment: to recap - step 1 and 3 succeed - what is the output in 3, does it return a value?, and then - you see the error on step 4?

Comment: Yes 3 returned value but getting error on step 4 as mentioned in question.However when I am running above steps by removing step 4(disconnect from db),I am getting RuntimePyRaisable exception driver not found.

Comment: Well `self._dbconnection` is an instance variable, initialized in `connect_to_database_using_custom_params()`; and for that error to happen - `Attribute error: None type object has no attribute close`, it means it has not been set in the connect keyword. But for that to happen, steps 1 and 3 should have thrown errors, before you got to step 4... Can you try step 4 without the library name, e.g. `${result}=  Query  ${query}` and see does this change anything?

Comment: The error on step 5 is unrelated - you don't have the driver you're passing installed.

Comment: We have separate drivers installed for both DB connections and both tests (i.e., Oracle and DB2 connections) run perfectly when run individually. However, the above mentioned issue is seen only when both tests are run in a sequence i.e., while connecting to Oracle DB  after running DB2  scenario and vice versa.

Comment: So are you saying that if the fifth action - `connect to database using params jaydebeapi  '${jdbcdriver}'`  - is missing, then the 4th one - `disconnect from database` does not throw the exception?